# trouble with jquery and traversing the DOM to select the appropriate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys i have the below html for a number of products on my website,

it displays a line with product title, price, qty wanted and a checkbox called buy.
qty input is disabled at the moment.

So what i want to do is, 
*if the checkbox is clicked i want the input qty to set to 1 and i want it to become enabled.*

I seem to be having some trouble doing this. Could any one help
Now i can have multiple product i.e there will be multiple table-products divs within my html page.

i have tried using jQuery to change the details but i dont seem to be able to get access to certain elements.

so basically for each table-product i would like to put a click listener on the check box that will set the value of the input-text i.e qty text field.

so of the below there could be 20 on a page.

```
<div class="table-products">
    <div class="table-top-title">
        My Spelling Workbook F
    </div>
    <div class="table-top-price">
        <div class="price-box">
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1"><span class="price">€6.95</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-top-qty">
        <fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
            <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="1"> <legend>Add Items to Cart</legend> <span class="qty-box"><label for="qty1">Qty:</label> <input name="qty1" disabled="disabled" value="0" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty1" maxlength="12"></span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="table-top-details">
        <input type="checkbox" name="buyMe" value="buy" class="add-checkbox">
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

here is the javascript i have tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('hello');

    var thischeck;
    jQuery(".table-products").ready(function(e) {
        //var catTable = jQuery(this);
        var qtyInput = jQuery(this).children('.input-text');

        jQuery('.add-checkbox').click(function() {
            console.log(jQuery(this).html());
            thischeck = jQuery(this);
            if (thischeck.is(':checked'))
            {
                jQuery(qtyInput).first().val('1');
                jQuery(qtyInput).first().prop('disabled', false);
            } else {

                }

        });

    });
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery spelled out because of another plugin or library that also utilizes the $ so as to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most direct method, but this should work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.add-checkbox').on('click', function() {
      jQuery(this)
         .parents('.table-products')
         .find('input.input-text')
         .val('1')
         .removeAttr('disabled');
   });
});
```

Comment: I liked your initial approach more as it does no expensive use of .parents() but that is just personal ;)

Comment: I agree on the use of parents() is not as desirable.  @molleman - this just listens for any click events on any elements, now or added to the dom later that match the selector `.add-checkbox`.  It then just grabs the parent div, then looks for the `.input-text` field inside.  So as long as the html structure stays the same, this should work. http://api.jquery.com/on/ - for reference.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
jQuery('.add-checkbox').change(function() {
```

the problem is one the one hand that you observe click and not change, so use change rather as it really triggers after the state change

```
var qtyInput = jQuery(this).children('.input-text');
```

another thing is that the input is no direct child of .table-products

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smxVg/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery('input:checkbox.add-checkbox').on('change', function() {
        jQuery(this)
            .parent()
            .prev('div.table-top-qty')
            .find('fieldset input:disabled.qty')
            .val(this.checked | 0)
            .attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in the right direction. Based on jQuery 1.7.2 (I saw your prop call and am guessing that's what you're using).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var thischeck;
    $('.table-products').on('click', '.add-checkbox', function() {

        var qtyInput = $(this).parents('.table-products').find('.input-text');
        thischeck = $(this);
        if (thischeck.prop('checked')) {
            $(qtyInput).val('1').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(qtyInput).val('0').prop('disabled', true);
        }

    });
});
```

Removing the property for some reason tends to prevent it from being re-added. This works with multiple tables. For your conflict, just replace the $'s with jQuery.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KqtS7/5/